# gulp trust-dev-cert gives the error: ReferenceError: primordials is not defined

Tags: spfx, gulp

I'm setting up a development environment for SP2019.

I've installed;

- Node.js 14.15.0
- gulp CLI 2.3.0 and Local 3.9.1
- yeoman 4.3.0
- @microsoft/generator-sharepoint 1.12.1

Once I've started my new project by running,

```
yo @microsoft/sharepoint
```

And come to trusting the dev certificate by running

```
gulp trust-dev-cert
```

I'm getting an error

```
ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
    at fs.js:45:5
    at req_ (U:\SPFx\node_modules\natives\index.js:143:24)
    at Object.req [as require] (U:\SPFx\node_modules\natives\index.js:55:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (U:\SPFx\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\graceful-fs\fs.js:1:37)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (U:\SPFx\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:3:27)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
About to exit with code: 1
Process terminated before summary could be written, possible error in async code not continuing!
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue stems from the version of node JS and gulp installed.

The easiest solutions would be to downgrade your node to an earlier version of node JS (***not recommended***) or you upgrade your gulp and dependent packages to a version where that issue is resolved.

See the thread below for in-depth discussion regarding this issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55921442/how-to-fix-referenceerror-primordials-is-not-defined-in-node-js

Answer (score 0):

As it happens, in my case it was nothing to do with the Node version, it was the Gulp version.

Documentation for setting up the SPFx enviornment suggested I needed Gulp 3.9.1 in fact I needed 4+. I ran the below and the certificate was promted for as expected.

```
npm install gulp@^4.0.2
```

This was mentioned in the setup but it was easily overlooked.